# $4\sin^2{v}-5\sin(v)+1=0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**Problem:** If the angle $v$ is acute such that the equation $4\sin^2{v}-5\sin(v)+1=0$ holds, then $v$ belongs in the interval

a) $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{12}\right);$

b) $\left(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{4}\right);$

c) $\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}\right);$

d) None of the above.

Substituting $t=\sin{v}$ gives me the solutions $t_1=1$ and $t_2=1/4$. Since the angle is acute, meaning that $0<v<\pi/2$, we can disregards $t_1$. So this leaves me with $\sin{v}=1/4.$ Plotting this and the given interval in b) I get the following figure:

[image]

Here I can see that the interval in b) does not contain the value of $\sin{v},$ and since the interval in c) $>$ interval in b), c) is incorrect as well. This leaves me with having to examine a). The problem here is that I need to check the relation between $\sin{v}=1/4$ and $\sin{\pi/12}$.

If $\sin{\frac{\pi}{12}}>\frac{1}{4}$ then a) is correct answer. If $\sin{\frac{\pi}{12}}<\frac{1}{4}$, then $d)$ is the correct answer.

Since $\sin{\pi/12}=\sin(15)=\sin({45-30})$, I can use the additionformula for sinus function. I get that $\sin{\pi/12}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}.$ Let's assume that $$\frac{1}{4}<\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}},$$

Either I have to show that this equality is true or not, or I have to find another way to solve this problem because this question only gives 1 point in a test and should take no more than a few minutes to solve, not 45 minutes. Any simplification that tells me that $\sin{\pi/12}>\frac{1}{4}$ is welcome.

Comment: My guess is, if you are supposed to do this in say two or three minutes, then you should *know* the value of sin $15$ by heart, and then checking the above inequality should not take more than two minutes.

Comment: $\sin x < x$ in $[0,\pi/2]$ therefore as $0.25<\pi/12$ the answer is (a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the identity $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ with $x=\pi/12$ you should get
$$ \frac 1 4 = \sin(\pi/12)\cos(\pi/12).$$
Hence, $\sin(\pi/12)>\frac 1 4$.

Another approach is to use the concavity of $\sin(x)$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ to deduce:
$$ \frac 1 2 [\sin(2x)+\sin(0)]<\sin(x).$$

Comment: This was clever! Thanks!